# MongoDB won't work as a standalone EC2 AWS instance CENTOS 7

Tags: linux, mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, centos7

I have been trying to setup Mongodb on one EC2 instance and want it to be used as the database for my currently functioning api on another EC2 instance. I am using Centos 7.

I tried to follow these [instructions](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/platforms/amazon-ec2/#deploy-mongodb-ec2) on the mongodb site for how to do exactly this but it appears that they are out of date. An obvious issue is that `/dev/xvdf /dev/xvdg /dev/xvdh or the sd* equivalents` do not exist. Instead I mounted my log/data/journal to `/dev/xvda1`.

When I run `sudo service mongod start` the below is output:

```
● mongod.service - High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2018-02-12 16:47:57 UTC; 14s ago
     Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
  Process: 8348 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod $OPTIONS (code=exited, status=100)
  Process: 8345 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chmod 0755 /var/run/mongodb (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 8343 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chown mongod:mongod /var/run/mongodb (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 8342 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mkdir -p /var/run/mongodb (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Feb 12 16:47:57 ip-111-11-4-246.us-east-2.compute.internal systemd[1]: Starting High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database...
Feb 12 16:47:57 ip-111-11-4-246.us-east-2.compute.internal mongod[8348]: about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
Feb 12 16:47:57 ip-111-11-4-246.us-east-2.compute.internal mongod[8348]: forked process: 8351
Feb 12 16:47:57 ip-111-11-4-246.us-east-2.compute.internal mongod[8348]: ERROR: child process failed, exited with error number 100
Feb 12 16:47:57 ip-111-11-4-246.us-east-2.compute.internal mongod[8348]: To see additional information in this output, start without the "--fork" option.
Feb 12 16:47:57 ip-111-11-4-246.us-east-2.compute.internal systemd[1]: mongod.service: control process exited, code=exited status=100
Feb 12 16:47:57 ip-111-11-4-246.us-east-2.compute.internal systemd[1]: Failed to start High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database.
Feb 12 16:47:57 ip-111-11-4-246.us-east-2.compute.internal systemd[1]: Unit mongod.service entered failed state.
Feb 12 16:47:57 ip-111-11-4-246.us-east-2.compute.internal systemd[1]: mongod.service failed.
```

Based upon this [article](https://www.attosol.com/how-to-install-mongodb-in-aws-linux-step-by-step/)  I have run mongod --storageEngine wiredTiger --dbpath /data and it will open mongo but will end with `waiting for connections on port 27017` which can then be opened on another instance of mongo but that is not maintainable nor accessible to my server.

This is my full history for this application. Note (this is a new ec2 instance for the sake of trying to restart the process.)

```
    1  lsls
    2  ls
    3  cd ../..
    4  ls
    5  cd etc
    6  ls
    7  cd yum.repos.d/
    8  ls
    9  touch mongodb-org-3.6.repo
   10  sudo touch mongodb-org-3.6.repo
   11  sudo vi mongodb-org-3.6.repo
   12  sudo yum -y update && sudo yum install -y mongodb-org-server     mongodb-org-shell mongodb-org-tools
   13  ls
   14  cd ../../..
   15  ls
   16  sudo mkdir /data /log /journal
   17  sudo mkfs.xfs /dev/xvda1
   18  echo '/dev/xvdf /data xfs defaults,auto,noatime,noexec 0 0
/dev/xvdg /journal xfs defaults,auto,noatime,noexec 0 0
/dev/xvdh /log xfs defaults,auto,noatime,noexec 0 0' | sudo tee -a /etc/fstab
   19  sudo mount /data
   20  sudo mount /dev/xvda1 /data
   21  sudo mount /dev/xvda1 /log
   22  sudo mount /dev/xvda1 /journal
   23  sudo mount /dev/xvda1 /data
   24  sudo chown mongod:mongod /data /journal /log
   25  sudo ln -s /journal /data/journal
   26  sudo vi etc/mongod.conf
   27  cd ../..
   28  ls
   29  echo '* soft nofile 64000
* hard nofile 64000
* soft nproc 64000
* hard nproc 64000' | sudo tee /etc/security/limits.d/90-mongodb.conf
   30  echo 'ACTION=="add|change", KERNEL=="xvda1", ATTR{bdi/read_ahead_kb}="0"' | sudo tee -a /etc/udev/rules.d/85-ebs.rules
   31  sudo service mongod start --storageEngine wiredTiger
   32  sudo service mongod start
   33  journalctl -xe
   34  systemctl status mongod.service
   35  mongo
   36  mongod --storageEngine wiredTiger --dbpath /data --fork --logpath
   37  mongod --storageEngine wiredTiger --dbpath /data --fork --logpath /log
   38  cd log
   39  ls
   40  cd log
   41  ls
   42  cd ..
   43  cd log
   44  sudo touch mongo.log
   45  cd ..
   46  mongod --storageEngine wiredTiger --dbpath /data --fork --logpath /log
   47  mongod --storageEngine wiredTiger --dbpath /data --fork --logpath /log/mongo.log
   48  --fork mongod --storageEngine wiredTiger --dbpath /data --logpath /log/mongo.log
   49  sudo service mongod start
   50  systemctl status mongod.service
   51  systemctl status mongod.service --fork
   52  sudo setenforce 0
   53  systemctl status mongod.service --fork
   54  sudo service mongod start
   55  ls -Z
   56  sudo chcon -Rv --type=mongod_log_t $logpath
   57  sudo blockdev --setra 0 /dev/xvda1
   58  echo 'ACTION=="add|change", KERNEL=="xvda1", ATTR{bdi/read_ahead_kb}="0"' | sudo tee -a /etc/udev/rules.d/85-ebs.rules
   59  /dev/mapper/my_vol /var/lib/mongodb xfs noatime,noexec 0 0
   60  sudo chown mongod:mongod /data /journal /log
   61  sudo chmod 777 /data /journal /log
   62  sudo chmod 777 /data /journal /logsudo ln -s /journal /data/journal
   63  ls
   64  sudo ln -s /journal /data/journal
   65  sudo chmod 400 /data /journal /logsudo ln -s /journal /data/journal
   66  sudo service mongod start
   67  systemctl status mongod.service
   68  sudo systemctl start mongod.service
   69  systemctl status mongod.service
   70  sudo -u mongod /usr/bin/mongod -f /etc/mongod1.conf
   71  sudo vi etc/mongod.conf
   72  history
```

Comment: Considering the history, I'd advise to take a look at Atlas. Maintaining mongodb requires some system administration background, which may result with quite long learning curve. The command 71 looks promising, but there is no hints what you have changed in the config, and you didn't try to use it after the change.

Comment: Unfortunately, what I use beyond this point is not up to me. I have a version working with the ` sudo mongod --storageEngine wiredTiger --dbpath /data --bind_ip_all` and then running mongo on another instance/localhost. However, it all closes once I close my instance. Do you know of a way to keep it open even if I ssh out similar to how `PM2` keep an api servers running?

Answer (score 2):

I got it to work.

`sudo mongod --storageEngine wiredTiger --dbpath /data --bind_ip_all` runs the application.

`sudo chkconfig mongod on` this keeps it permanently running in the background.

To be honest, the final version is a little different than above but I cannot quite figure out what other changes made it work unfortunately.

Comment: Or this one: mongod --dbpath /var/lib/mongo --logpath /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log --fork

Answer (score 0):

A day savior to this issue is here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1103513/765684

 Just in case anybody reached here first by google search like I did.